# Calculating median of multiple polylines in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I am working with several polylines of mean monthly Arctic sea ice extent for the month of September; one line per year from 1979 - 2010.

I would like to summarize the polylines by showing the median (of the mean monthly) ice extents over two different time periods (1979-1999 and 2000-2010).

Is there at tool that will calculate this new median line for me?

Answer (score 2):

When you say the median ice extents I assume you are referring to the distance *between* the "shorelines" of the ice sheets between your time periods. Amending your question with a simple image would resolve any confusion in what you are asking. There is the [DSAS](http://woodshole.er.usgs.gov/project-pages/DSAS/) tool which may solve your question. It appears that version 4.3.473 is compatible with ArcGIS 10.0.